# arr использовать ресурсы из главного проекта

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Есть два проекта. Один собирается в arr модуль и добавляется во второй(в главный).
В arr нужно использовать некоторые цвета и иконки из главного проекта. Конечно сейчас я получаю ошибку, что таких ресурсов нет, но когда проекты соединятся, то будут. Просто копировать -  не вариант, может можно как то указать что ресурсы будут в будущем или что нужно их взять из такого-то проекта?

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Никак нельзя указать на использование несуществующих ресурсов.

Вам надо добавить иконки и прочие ресурсы в проект либы. После, при подключении этой либы вы можете подставить уже нужные для конкретного проекта ресурсы.